# Delay url ImageView load until view is on screen?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm loading many images from a server, and can't hammer the server with all those requests at once. I want to only load the images once they've scrolled into view on screen, similar to the Facebook iPhone app.

Anybody know how to do this in Titanium?

I think I've seen a clue in the Kitchen Sink / YQL demo: It appears that a table will provide this functionality to the ImageView. Am going to test it...

Comment: I found that the delayed load is not activated if a table refresh style has been set. (1.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the table will only load the images for the cells once the row is visible.

Comment: FYI, I first tested with Scrollable View, and it does something similar. It seems to only load images for the current and next two screens. Sometimes, however, it does go ahead and load them all.

Comment: As @Dogweather says, this isn't always the case - try providing URLs to images that don't exist and watch the output in Titanium Developer - I've observed 404 messages for images that aren't currently visible on screen which suggests Appcelerator isn't waiting til they're visible before loading them.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Ignore below, it seems Appcelerator doesn't wait until the images are rendered before requesting the image data. Sounds like a bug.

That sounds right to me. A table (on iOS, at least) will lazy-load its cells, not processing them until they are on the screen. Rather than adding loads of images to a view, if you create table cells instead and insert the images into them they'll be loaded on demand. You can always style the table so it doesn't look like they're in a table, if you don't want that effect.

```
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    separatorColor: '#FFF' // Use this to hide the separator if you don't want it to look like a table
});

var images = []; // This contains your image views

var data = [];

for(var i=0, n=images.length; i<n; i++) {

    var cell = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        className: 'image' // boosts performance
    });

    cell.add(images[i]);

    data.push(cell);

}

table.data = data;

// Then just add the table to your window
```

Comment: there is no `createTableViewCell` or `tableClass` in Appcelerator